# Javascript Multiple menu. If i click on one ul i want the other to close. (toogle). It keeps being open, how to fix?

Tags: javascript

Hopefully you can help me out with my problem.
Been annoying be for quite some time now.

Trying to make my menu work.

When i click on a block i want it to open, and close the other tab "if" another one is open.

Best regards jfb

**HERE IS JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZWZu/
*INCLUDES HTML, CSS, JS(jQuery)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.ac-menu .topLevel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        if($('.ac-menu .topLevel ul').hasClass('open') === true){
        $('.ac-menu .topLevel ul').removeClass('open'); 
        $('.ac-menu .topLevel ul').addClass('closed');  
        $('.ac-menu .topLevel ul').slideUp(300);

    }
        if($(this).next('ul').hasClass('closed') === true){ 
        $(this).next('ul').removeClass('closed');           
        $(this).next('ul').slideDown(300);
        $(this).next('ul').addClass('open');
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: can you post your html ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please post the html/css that goes with this? A link to the problem on jsfiddle.net would help us to help you too.

Comment: When i try to load it at jsfiddle. Is gives me the error: {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: Working now on fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you use JQuery, try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $('.ac-menu .topLevel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('.ac-menu ul.open').removeClass('open').addClass('closed').slideUp(300);    
    $(this).next('ul.closed').removeClass('closed').slideDown(300).addClass('open');
  });
});
```

Basically the idea behind this is that with `ul.open` or `ul.closed` selector you will only select the `ul`s which have that specific class set. If there are none - then JQuery will return an empty set and will not apply those operations to anything - that is the way JQuery works. Furthermore, it allows you to chain your commands, like shown in my example.

Comment: Does not seem to work.
Same issue. When i open a ul and open another ul. The first ul still wont close.

Comment: Hard to tell. If your page is accessible from the web I could look into it.

Comment: Working now! Brilliant! Thank you mate!

Abit wierd tho, i was using:

      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
But when i hardcode it, just above the menu. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mido_rizk007/3ZWZu/7/)

i add `topLevel` class to li instead of `a href`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ac-menu li.topLevel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isClosed = $(this).find('ul').hasClass('closed');
    $('.ac-menu li.topLevel ul').removeClass('open').addClass('closed').slideUp(300);
    if( isClosed){
        $(this).find('ul').addClass('open').removeClass('closed').slideDown(300);
    }
 });
});
```